# Why do you have to set both id and pk to None to copy a Django model with inheritance?

Tags: django, django-models

The Django docs recommend [copying a model instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances) thus:

```
original.pk = None
original.save()
```

But if you "use inheritance" -- apparently meaning if the model's class is a subclass of a subclass of `models.Model` -- you need to do it slightly differently.

Specifically, the doc says:

> Due to how inheritance works, you have to set both pk and id to None:

and gives an example analogous to this:

```
original.pk = None
original.id = None
original.save()
```

This seems kludgey. In any case, I'd like to understand what's going on. Why does using inheritance require you to set the `id` field to `None` also? Don't all Django models inherit from `models.Model` in any case?

(NOTE: I'm omitting the bit from the doc about copying m2m fields, which incidentally seems even more kludgey.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because MTI (Multiple Table Inheritance), the type you're talking about here, stores the object across multiple tables. Take this example:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    ...

class Dog(Animal):
    ...
```

When you create a `Dog`, all the fields on `Animal` are saved into the table for `Animal`, and just the fields directly on `Dog` are saved to the table for `Dog`. When you lookup the `Dog` later, Django queries both tables and stitches them together.

Both tables, however need primary keys, and Django uses `AutoField`s for that, which are simply positive integer fields. So `Dog` has an id and `Animal` has an id. The `pk` is filled with the id for the `Animal` part because this is the main piece, and `Dog`'s id doesn't matter. However, if you're going to make a copy, you need to copy both pieces. Otherwise, the `Animal` part will of the copy will not get it's own `Dog` part of the copy.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Followup question: this isn't needed in the case of an abstract base-class, right? I.e. if `Animal` were abstract, then the normal copy approach of just `dog.pk = None` would be fine, yes?

Comment: Optional followup question #2: is it just me, or is it sort of odd that Django models don't have a `copy` method that takes care of all this for you? This has been discussed in a [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4027) for 5 years...

Comment: I think people's opinions of what is and isn't important can diverge greatly. In the last 2 years of writing and refactoring Django code daily, I've never once needed to make a copy of an object. That's not to say there's not plenty of people that do, but personally, whether Django adds a copy function or not does not concern me at all. You have to assume others, even others on the core dev team share my apathy.

Comment: Fair enough re: followup question #2. Less subjectively :-), ok to just set `pk` to `None` for a model using an abstract base class (which itself inherits from `models.Model`)?

Comment: Yes, this is only an issue with MTI, any other type of inheritance or standard models won't have a problem because there's only one table involved.